# Razor HiddenFor Retain Leading Zeroes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor

Simple question

view model

```
public string Plu { get; set; } = string.Empty;
```

Razor page

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Plu)
```

In controller

```
model.Plu = "00000000124"
```

Html result

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Plu: field is required." id="Plu" name="Plu" type="hidden" value="124">
```

Note, the value is now 124 removing leading zeroes.  If the length of the string (and number of leading zeroes) is unknown at compile time something like a formatting string won't work (though how to do that would be helpful too).

How do I retain the leading zeroes?  Do I simply have to forgo using the HiddenFor and create the field manually?

EDITS:
as stated in comments this block properly displays zeroes.

```
    <div class="col-8">
       @Model.Plu
    </div>
```

And this one strips the leading zeroes just like HiddenFor

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Plu)
```

.NET6 page.  I'm not aware of any kind of overriding going on.  Going to the definitions for HiddenFor/TextBoxFor takes me to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.IHtmlContent

I must be missing something....

EDIT2:  I have tested this in another project and the zeroes aren't stripped.  There must be some kind of configuration doing it :-/

Comment: Just a thought, you could add some character to the beginning that then gets stripped on the controller side.  eg. "+0000000000124".  There is probably a better way, but at least a decent last resort.

Comment: What versions of razor and asp.net[-core] are you using?

Comment: The type of `Plu` is string not int, Why it will remove zeroes before 124? I tried it in razor page (.net 6) and it works fine.

Comment: version is .net6.  I can't add characters to the beginning because I don't know how many to add.  To XinranShen: agree 100%!  It seems very strange to me!  I can even add <div class="col-8">@Model.Plu </div> to the page and the zeroes appear, but using HiddenFor they are gone....

Comment: Have you checked the difference between your two projects? It is so strange for that situation.

Comment: I've poked around a bit in the .csProj and the starup configs, nothing stands out.  I will say the project having the issue was started as an API project rather than a web project but I have a hard time believing that's the problem.